# What's Jersey's default exception handling? (if an ExceptionMapper is NOT provided)

Tags: java, http, jersey

What's Jersey's default exception handling (when ExceptionMapper is NOT provided)?

Example:

```
@GET
@Path("/rest")
public String rest() {
  throw new RuntimeException("Wonder what would happen...");
}
```

What would the result be? What would return in the HTTP status and content?

Comment: Why ask when you can try?

Comment: It's called knowledge sharing. Asking is also important. Giving the opportunity for others to answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your function have to return a Response object (javax.ws.rs.core.Response).

```
@GET
@Path("/rest")
public Response invokeSomething() {
   return Response.ok("Some string").build();
}
```

The method ok return the 202 resoponse with Object serialised in annotation class. Es:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class ....
```

This annotation mean that my service consume a json and my response is a json.

Then, when you want return an error you have to return a code 500.
In your exemple:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/rest")
    public Response invokeSomething() {
       return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("exeption message").build();
    }
```